# Where are the 31 secret keys?

Tags: tales-from-the-minus-lab

In [Tales from the Minus Lab](http://www.theminuslab.com/), where are the 31 secret keys?

I'm able to get four, but I am missing the others. Here are the keys I already have:

- one in the water place in the hamster cage,
- one inside a yellow boot,
- one at the root of the tree, below the floor,
- one in the box lying on the floor, near the tree.

Since there are checkpoints but no save system, I cannot manage to find all the keys.

Comment: The game has received an honorable mention for [IGF 2013](http://www.igf.com/02finalists.html).

Comment: btw i just found out that when you press 4 once you are in the tree house you can supposedly unlock the full range of minimization and maximization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this video has a lot of them (not all):

Here are all of the keys:

1. one in the water place in the hamster cage,
2. one inside a yellow boot,
3. one at the root of the tree, below the floor,
4. one in the box lying on the floor, near the tree.
5. on inside the cup near the dollhouse
6. one under floor next to the beaker (then through a tunnel) watch poison goo
7. one in a juice carton in the trashcan
8. train next to hamster cage
9. inside the volcano next to the hamster cage
10. inside the boat right next to that volcano (need to get into crystal ball)
11. behind pencil sharpener (tiny ladybug tiny)
12. plant next to the stapler
13. drawer next to the tree trunk
14. corner behind the tree
15. Inside the tree next to blue mushroom (have to climb the tree you can do it)
16. right below that also inside the tree
17. behind the spinning wind turbine (next to the tree)
18. inside the maze on the center table
19. one next to bottom gear (middle table below the vials you need to be tiny)
20. then on the top gear near green vial (tiny)
21. climb the ruler on the middle table (obvious)
22. remember the volcano there is another key under the mask you need to be very tiny (its not inside the volcano but on its base)
23. there are two inside the server/computer/chip.
24. a pot next to the server (very tiny)
25. inside the clock on the wall (same wall tree grew into)
26. tower of the same clock (the left one)
27. cheese (middle table)
28. corner of the white cupboard inside its groves next to the trashcan (this one is tricky walk to the cupboard on the right side then shrink)
29. black box in the middle temple you can climb it from the side.

For others wanting to play this game

**Watch out** pressing escape twice will turn of the game it is really frustrating as im used to other games and I just press escape when i want to pause and when i want to resume i press escape again. This game has no resume and it can take a while to load so if you press escape its game over! its really stupid design.

I downloaded the game just to look for them. Im dedicated so far I found one in the chips (the ones next to the hamster cage one) just jump inside shrink and look between the chips to find it

I will keep looking and will update this answer as I find new ones.

Comment: It would be easier if we could save the game somehow.

Comment: @wok I know and there are tons of bugs. I think the video has all of the keys the first one is found at 8:50

Comment: I guess I will still list them as Im going to find them to insure quality answer :D

Comment: Wow! Good job, Xitcod13!

Comment: @wok man it took a while. Haha its a fun game though stupid design of the  interface with no saves and esc exists the game and buggy but fun. :) Also i dont mention this but you need to use chips to lower a mini- bridge next to the tree (or you could just climb the tree like i did but its hard)

Comment: Just to be sure, the key in the chips is the 30th?

Comment: yes. Also I think i skipped one but it should be next to another key, i probably just forgot to write it down :( I will try to figure out which i missed lol...

Comment: Do not push too hard, man! You already did a great job!